# How to change the font of the output cell in Jupyter Lab

Tags: fonts, jupyter, font-size, jupyter-lab

I want to change the font face for the output area of a Jupyter cell in Jupyter Lab. Is there some property in the settings JSON that may allow me to do so?

For clarity, I've attached a screenshot:

[image]

I want to change the font of `Hello` written in white

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Hello vulkan and welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't attach links to images in your questions, but rather inline them next time.

Comment: Actually, stackoverflow wasn't allowing me to attach an image inline because I didn't have enough reputation. But thanks a lot!